# .Net Core 3.1 WPFのDesignDataが表示されない

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

VisualStudio Community 2019
Version 16.6.1
TargetFramework .NET Core 3.1

上記環境にてWPFアプリを作成し始めましたが、
XAMLデザイナーでのDesignDataおよびDesignInstanceが機能しません。

正確には、BindingのIntellisenceは機能する為、型情報は取得できているようですが
実際のデータが表示されないというものです。

.NetFrameworkプロジェクトで実際に表示できていたデザインデータを
そのままコピーし、ビルドアクションを「DesignData」及び
「DesignDataWithDesignTimeCreatableTypes」で
どちらも試してみましたが、データが表示されません。

.NET Coreではまだデザイン時のデータ表示には対応していないのでしょうか。

Comment: その元々のプロジェクトを紹介したり、その時の動作を提示したりして、さらに.NET Coreでどうなっているか追記すれば他の人が検証や回答しやすくなるでしょう。

Comment: 新しい版で改善されているかも。[XAML ツール (WPF、UWP、Xamarin.Forms) - Visual Studio 2019 バージョン 16.7 リリース ノート](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#xaml-tools-wpf-uwp--xamarinforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kunifさんのコメントから
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.7.2
にて、デザインデータのプレビューが可能になっていることを確認しました。
ViewModelを用いた、DesignInstanceからでもプレビュー可能なようです。
しかし、.NETFrameworkでは以下のような条件でデザイン時の切り分けが
できましたが、それには対応していないようです。

```
if(LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
```

現時点では、実行時は引数無しコンストラクタが呼ばれることは無い
などの条件であれば使用可能かと思っています。